# Filter a part of txt string that not exist in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, leaflet, geojson

I have properties in a geojson polygon file that are weekdays in different combinations like this:
Mon-Fri or Tue-Fri or Tue,Wed,Fri or Mon,Thu or Wed-Fri etc..

What I need is to show polygons in Leaflet that has not the value "Mon" (Monday) in the text string.
How can I filter this out? I'm using this code for other filtrations...

```
var non_mon = new L.layerGroup();
$.getJSON("..data/polygons.geojson", function(json) {
 var vectorGrid =  L.vectorGrid.slicer(json, {
                  maxZoom: 20,
                  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                      sliced: function(properties, zoom){
                      var dayint = properties.Days_1

                      if (dayint = "does not have Mån" ){
                        return{
                      weight: 0.5,
                      color: '#ffffff',
                      opacity: 1,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#ff0000',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else {
                      return {
                      weight: 0,
                      fill: false,
                      stroke: false    
                      }
                     }
                     }},
                     interactive: true,
                   })
     .on('click', function(e) {
  var properties = e.layer.properties;
  L.popup()
    .setContent(
      "<b>Weekdays</b>" + '\xa0\xa0' + properties.Days_1 + '</b>' +
      "<br>Date from: " + '<i>' + properties.Date + '</i>' )
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .openOn(map);
                   })
vectorGrid.addTo(non_mon)

            })
```

This is how the GeoJSON looks like

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Mån-Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Tis-Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Ons-Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Tors,Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Mån,Ons,Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Tis,Ons-Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Ons,Tors" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Mån" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Tis" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Ons" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Tors" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Tis-Tors" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Mån-Tors" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": "Ons,Fre" },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Days_1": null },
```

Comment: Could you post some sample GeoJSON so the exact format is clear?

Comment: @Mathyn, done, did change "Weekdays_1" to more correct "Days_1" properties

Comment: better sample I guess.... stripped but more of the format of weekdays. Need to find those rows that has no "Mån", means no Monday on the drivers list

Answer (score 1):

Alright so you want to filter all rows for which the 'Days_1' property does not contain the string 'Mån'. You could do this like this:

```
var geoJson = [...]; // Your GeoJSON

// After this function call 'filtered' contains the filtered list of GeoJSON features
var filtered = geoJson.filter(
    function(element) {
        // We are only interested in elements which do not contain 'Mån'
        return element.indexOf("Mån") != -1;
    }
);
```

In this example we use the 'filter' method part of the array prototype. The filter method will call the passed function for each element in the array. You can then return true to retain the element or false to filter the element. The final result will be returned as a new array.

Comment: Not being able to implement you suggestions, I'm getting error that geoJson is not valid. vectorGrid use function(json) if that is not matching. Its a large polygon (27Mb) GeoJson file so I need to use a vectorGrid function to not slow down the webpage. I added one row ""getJSON" that should have been there from beginning. Any suggestion to implement your suggestion into this one... by the way there is is also "null" values in the properties if that makes a problem...

Comment: I'm not very familiair with Leaflet but the error seems to suggest the GeoJSON you pass into the VectorGrid constructor is somehow malfored (e.g. invalid GeoJSON as you already stated). Please double check the [documentation](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html) to see if you've made a mistake. I'm guessing in this case you would need to pass the GeoJSON as a 'FeatureCollection'.